# How to open website after specific time in c++?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  ShellExecute(0, 0, L"www.ldjgsdoij.com", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW ); 
  int i;cin>>i;
  return 0;
}
```

How to open this web **www.ldjgsdoij.com** after 15 minutes even if the client
has runned exe file and closed it?

Comment: I don't think it is possible , you MUST have a process running in background.

Comment: why not try `schtasks` command in windows?

Comment: @mohammedawni do you intend to stay that way? I don't see what yelling "I am novice!!!!" helps you. Just google `at` and `schtasks` then. Perhaps you'll remember a bit of it, and in some year(s) you won't be novice anymore.

Answer (score 4):

- you can use C++11 [Chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) functions for time.
  see also Stackoverflow answer [How to create timer events using C++ 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650885/how-to-create-timer-events-using-c-11)
- I think the best way it to use [Schedule Tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) in Windows or [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Linux
- For open URLs see the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849656/launch-a-url-in-a-new-window-using-c-windows) on open browser window